# R: Fast query/match dataframe

Tags: r, performance

Say, I have a dataframe like below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

dfr <- data.frame(name=c("bill","john","alice","sara"),
job=c("accounting","business","finance","business"),
stringsAsFactors=F)

   name        job
1  bill accounting
2  john   business
3 alice    finance
4  sara   business
```

And I have a query (character vector) with name.

```
qe <- c("john","bill","mark","bill")
```

I would like to search each element of the query in the dataframe position 'name' and retrieve the whole row given some conditions:

- Duplicates in query must be preserved
- Order of query must be preserved
- Unmatched queries must be preserved (with NA's added)

My attempt was the function below:

```
loopy <- function(qe=NULL,dfr=NULL)
{
  elist <- vector("list",length=length(qe))
  for(i in 1:length(qe))
  {
    g <- grep(qe[i],dfr$name)
    if(length(g)==0) {
      elist[[i]] <- data.frame(name=qe[i],job=NA,stringsAsFactors=F)
    }else{
      elist[[i]] <- dfr[g,]
    }
  }
  return(bind_rows(elist))
}

loopy(qe,dfr)

  name        job
1 john   business
2 bill accounting
3 mark       <NA>
4 bill accounting
```

It seems to work but is way too slow on my real data with several thousand rows. I thought I would try a dplyr approach.

```
dp_lj <- function(qe=NULL,dfr=NULL)
{
  edf <- data.frame(name=qe,stringsAsFactors=F)
  edf <- left_join(edf,dfr,by="name")
  return(edf)
}
dp_lj(qe,dfr)

  name        job
1 john   business
2 bill accounting
3 mark       <NA>
4 bill accounting
```

`left_join` seems to give the result I want. But, surprisingly, this was slower than my loopy function. Fiddling around, I came up with a match approach.

```
matchy <- function(qe=NULL,dfr=NULL)
{
  edf <- dfr[match(qe,dfr$name),]
  pos <- match(NA,edf$name)
  if(!is.na(pos)) edf[pos,]$name <- qe[pos]
  rownames(edf) <- 1:nrow(edf)
  return(edf)
}
matchy(qe,dfr)

  name        job
1 john   business
2 bill accounting
3 mark       <NA>
4 bill accounting
```

This is the fastest so far. An attempt using `%in%` didn't really work
`dfr[dfr$name %in% q,]`.

```
autoplot(microbenchmark(loopy(qe,dfr),dp_lj(qe,dfr),matchy(qe,dfr),times=500))

Unit: microseconds
            expr     min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
  loopy(qe, dfr) 426.274 461.0390  528.1194  481.7795  518.915 2659.955   500  b 
  dp_lj(qe, dfr) 919.311 982.9155 1146.0196 1030.1260 1129.088 4589.438   500   c
 matchy(qe, dfr) 128.396 154.4710  185.1209  169.0875  186.471  736.397   500 a
```

[image: autoplot]

I am curious if there are faster solutions that doesn't take too much effort. Also I havn't tested whether the performance seen here is comparable when run on real large datasets.

EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------------

Added a data.table approach as suggested.

```
dt <- function(qe=NULL,dfr=NULL)
{
  setDT(dfr)
  qe <- data.table(name=qe)
  merge(qe, dfr, "name", all.x = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
}
```

Tested using a query of length 18 and dataframe of 100,000 rows. Shows a better comparison of real-life performance.

```
mb <- microbenchmark(loopy(qe,dfr),dp_lj(qe,dfr),matchy(qe,dfr),dt(qe,dfr),times=200)
autoplot(mb)
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: You might check out the `fastmatch` package. This has a drop-in function for `match` that crushes `match` in multiple searches.

Comment: Did you run the benchmark with that tiny sample data? If so, the results are not reliable

Comment: I thought so too. I will try on a large dataset.

Comment: With a keyed data.table, `DT[query]` should be fast.

Comment: Also, in base R, why not use the single liner `data.frame(name=qe, job=dfr[match(qe, dfr$name), "job"])`?

Comment: @lmo If there are multiple matches, they want them all, but match only gives the first.

Comment: @Frank I guess it depends on what the OP means by "multiple matches." The code I provided returns the data.frame in the example, so duplicates in the query vector, qe, are not a problem. If you are worried about duplicates in the second argument of `match` (the table argument), then your point stands.

Comment: For my purpose, the table (dataframe) doesn't have duplicate names. Only the query does. But, I suppose, it would be nice to consider that situation as well.

Comment: Btw, you do not need to give default values to arguments and `arg=NULL` will just mean your function breaks in interesting ways when no arg is passed instead of readable errors like "arg not found".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) if you transform data to data.table each time

```
withDT <- function(qe=NULL,dfr=NULL) {
  dfr2 <- as.data.table(dfr)
  setkey(dfr2, name)
  return(dfr2[qe])
}

N <- 200000
set.seed(123)
dfr <- data.frame(name= sample(1:30, N, replace = T),
                  job=sample(c("accounting","business","finance","business"), N, replace = T),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
head(dfr)
qe <- 1:41

r <- microbenchmark(loopy(qe,dfr),dp_lj(qe,dfr),
                    matchy(qe,dfr),
                    withDT(qe, dfr),times=10)
autoplot(r)
r
Unit: milliseconds
            expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval cld
  loopy(qe, dfr) 2683.964539 2704.321688 2765.214321 2717.469448 2802.026508 3038.711852    10   b
  dp_lj(qe, dfr)   10.799809   11.251819   12.675861   12.028161   12.849094   18.555524    10  a 
 matchy(qe, dfr)    1.741636    1.863862    2.892739    2.336564    2.616785    9.003637    10  a 
 withDT(qe, dfr)    3.348534    4.007463    5.836388    5.936607    6.656327   10.751368    10  a
```

but if you create data.table once and set key once, then it is faster

```
dt <- as.data.table(dfr)
setkey(dt, name)

withDT2 <- function(qe=NULL,dfr=NULL) {
  return(dfr[qe])
}

all.equal(withDT(qe, dfr), withDT2(qe, dt))

r <- microbenchmark(loopy(qe,dfr),dp_lj(qe,dfr),
                    matchy(qe,dfr),
                    withDT(qe, dfr),
                    withDT2(qe, dt),times=10)
autoplot(r)
r
            expr         min          lq         mean       median          uq         max neval cld
  loopy(qe, dfr) 2721379.707 2753441.327 2822803.2351 2795276.9895 2862874.678 3060082.414    10   b
  dp_lj(qe, dfr)    9181.361    9769.071   11084.7774   10708.5405   11709.925   16254.730    10  a 
 matchy(qe, dfr)    1783.983    1785.265    2798.4553    2183.7020    2659.131    8235.637    10  a 
 withDT(qe, dfr)    3280.845    3725.156    5076.5360    4097.7685    4714.831   13630.247    10  a 
 withDT2(qe, dt)     244.131     272.683     792.7672     520.9835     612.733    3895.182    10  a
```